# How to recover vmx file for VMware images？

Tags: vmware

Accidentally, I removed a vmx file from a VMware image while it was running。

How can I recover this?

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: I think you're going to have to re-create it.

Good news: The VMDK holds the whole disk - so most of the "important" stuff is in there.

So, create a new VM - then configure the disk(s) to use the *existing* VMDK.

Also, this kind of question should really be posted on "superuser.com" - not "stackoverflow.com".

Comment: Ok. How to move this post to superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

1. The content of the vmx file should be logged into VMware's image log.
2. Copy the content like below to a file (these contents should be located between Configuration and USER DEFAULT in VMware's image log), and name this file like `example.vmx`.

   ```
   config.version = "8"
   virtualHW.version = "4"
   floppy0.present = "true"
   nvram = "VNTco012.nvram"
   deploymentPlatform = "windows"
   virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
   tools.upgrade.policy = "manual"
   powerType.powerOff = "default"
   powerType.powerOn = "default"
   powerType.suspend = "default"
   powerType.reset = "default"
   displayName = "VNTco012"
   extendedConfigFile = "VNTco012.vmxf"
   scsi0.present = "true"
   scsi0.sharedBus = "none"
   scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
   memsize = "2048"
   scsi0:0.present = "true"
   scsi0:0.fileName = "VNTco012.vmdk"
   scsi0:0.deviceType = "scsi-hardDisk"
   sched.scsi0:0.shares = "normal"
   ide0:0.present = "true"
   ide0:0.clientDevice = "true"
   ide0:0.fileName = "/usr/lib/vmware/isoimages/windows.iso"
   ide0:0.deviceType = "atapi-cdrom"
   ide0:0.startConnected = "false"
   floppy0.startConnected = "false"
   floppy0.fileName = "/dev/fd0"
   floppy0.clientDevice = "true"
   ethernet0.present = "true"
   ethernet0.networkName = "VM Network 1007"
   ethernet0.addressType = "vpx"
   ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:50:56:aa:40:b9"
   guestOSAltName = "Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition (32-bit)"
   guestOS = "winnetstandard"
   uuid.bios = "50 2a 7f e5 bc 42 27 8b-d0 04 3f 47 3c d8 3a ed"
   log.fileName = "vmware.log"
   snapshot.action = "keep"
   sched.cpu.min = "0"
   sched.cpu.units = "mhz"
   sched.cpu.shares = "normal"
   sched.mem.minsize = "0"
   sched.mem.shares = "normal"
   toolScripts.afterPowerOn = "true"
   toolScripts.afterResume = "true"
   toolScripts.beforeSuspend = "true"
   toolScripts.beforePowerOff = "true"
   scsi0:0.redo = ""
   tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
   vmware.tools.requiredversion = "7299"
   ethernet0.startConnected = "TRUE"
   tools.deployPkg.fileName = ""
   numvcpus = "2"
   scsi0:1.present = "true"
   scsi0:1.fileName = "VNTco012_1.vmdk"
   scsi0:1.deviceType = "scsi-hardDisk"
   ```
3. Start the image by opening `example.vmx`.

Answer (score 0):

There is as script for this advertised at

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023880

Personally I had trouble getting it to work on Mac OS ElCapitan. The script is unfortunately badly documented.

I tried the following steps:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023880
VMXFILENAME=$(sed -n 's/^.*Config file: .*\/\(.\+\)$/\1/p' vmware.log)
echo $VMXFILENAME
exit
echo -e "#\041/usr/bin/vmware" > ${VMXFILENAME}
echo '.encoding = "UTF-8"' >> ${VMXFILENAME}
sed -n '/DICT --- CONFIGURATION/,/DICT ---/ s/^.*DICT \+\(.\+\) = \(.\+\)$/\1 = "\2"/p' vmware.log >> ${VMXFILENAME}
```

so first I wanted to know whether the config filename is detected correctly.
A grep shows what to expect

```bsh
 grep "Config file:"  vmware.log
 2017-01-25T19:35:35.533+01:00| vmx| I125: Config file: /vmware/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx
```

but the script doesn't get the correct file name it shows an empty result.
So i replaced the line for getting the filename with

VMXFILENAME=`grep "Config file: " vmware.log | cut -f3 -d"|" | cut -f3 -d ":"`

which i personally find better understandable. First we look for the line that conains "Config file". In That line we look for the third field separated with a pipe sign and then for the third field separated by a colon. And yes indeed this determines the config file name.

Now lets see whether this will create a correct vmx file. First we make sure we do not override the original one so the last line is modified as:

```bsh
>> ${VMXFILENAME}.new
```

and now we can uncomment this part to test it. Before we do this we make sure a backup copy of our original vmx file is created (and only once if we need to restart this script ...)

```bsh
echo "trying to create a new $VMXFILENAME"
today=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
if [ -f $VMXFILENAME ]
then
  if [ ! -f $VMXFILENAME.$today ]
  then
    echo "creating backup of $VMXFILENAME as $VMXFILENAME.$today"
    mv $VMXFILENAME $VMXFILENAME.$today
  else
    echo "backup $VMXFILENAME.$today exists"
  fi
else
  echo "$VMXFILENAME not found" 1>&2
  if [ !-f $VMXFILENAME.$today ]
  then
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

and the second sed also does not work as expected (sigh ...)

So I ended up also replacing the sed with a few lines of awk

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1023880
VMXFILENAME=`grep "Config file: " vmware.log | cut -f3 -d"|" | cut -f3 -d ":"`
echo "trying to create a new $VMXFILENAME"
today=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
if [ -f $VMXFILENAME ] 
then
  if [ ! -f $VMXFILENAME.$today ]
  then
    echo "creating backup of $VMXFILENAME as $VMXFILENAME.$today"
    mv $VMXFILENAME $VMXFILENAME.$today
  else
    echo "backup $VMXFILENAME.$today exists"
  fi 
else
  echo "$VMXFILENAME not found" 1>&2
  if [ !-f $VMXFILENAME.$today ]
  then
    exit 1
  fi
fi
echo -e "#\041/usr/bin/vmware" > ${VMXFILENAME}
echo '.encoding = "UTF-8"' >> ${VMXFILENAME}
#sed -n '/DICT --- CONFIGURATION/,/DICT ---/ s/^.*DICT \+\(.\+\) = \(.\+\)$/\1 = "\2"/p' vmware.log 
gawk '
# use pipe sign as a field separator
BEGIN { FS="|" }
# check whether we are in the range of lines after DICT --CONFIGURATION
/DICT --- CONFIGURATION/ { inconfig=1;next }
/DICT --- [A-Z+]/        { inconfig=0;next }
/DICT/ && (inconfig==1) { 
          if (match($3,/.*DICT[ \t]+(.*)/,groups)) {
            print groups[1] 
          }
        }
' vmware.log >> ${VMXFILENAME}
echo "please check ${VMXFILENAME}"
```